# Spectral norm of matrices of i.i.d. bounded r.v. is sub-Gaussian

Tags: probability-inequalities, subgaussianity

The setting is $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ with each entry being i.i.d. bounded r.v. in $[a,b]$. The question is to prove $\Vert A\Vert_2$ is sub-Gaussian.

Intuitively I thought since $\{A_{ij}\}_{i,j=1,...,n}$ is bounded, then
$$\Vert A \Vert_2 = \sup_{\Vert v \Vert = 1} \vert v^TA^TAv\vert = \sup_{\Vert v \Vert = 1}\vert\sum_{i,j}v_iv_j(\sum_k A_{ki}A_{kj})\vert\leq \max(a^2,b^2)$$

Then $\Vert A\Vert_2$ is bounded so that it is sub-Gaussian. Is there any problem in the above process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a problem.

Suppose $v_i$ is $1$ for $i=1$ and 0 otherwise. Then
$$\sum_{i,j} v_iv_j\left(\sum_k A_{ki}A_{kj}\right)=\sum_k A_{k1}A_{k1}=\sum_k A_{k1}^2$$
and this is only bounded above by $\max (na^2, nb^2)$. Looking for a deterministic bound won't work; it doesn't take advantage of the randomness.

Next, simple computer experiments show that $\|A\|_2$ is large when $n$ is large, so we should expect even the probabilistic bounds to depend on $n$. Also, there are two definitions of sub-Gaussian out there, one requiring zero mean and one not. We must be using the one that doesn't, since $\|A\|_2$ clearly doesn't have zero mean.

Given the bounds $[a,b]$ and no other information, we're presumably supposed to use Hoeffding's inequality. To reduce the number of cases to consider, I'll assume $0<a$.  An obvious iid sum to apply the inequality to is the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_F^2=\sum_{ij} A_{ij}^2$.

By Hoeffding's inequality
$$P(|\|A\|_F^2-E[\|A\|_F^2]|>t)\leq 2\exp\frac{-2t^2}{n^2(b^2-a^2)^2}$$
so $\|A\|_F^2$ is sub-Gaussian and so $\left\|\|A\|_F\right\|_{\psi_2}$ is finite, where
$$\|X\|_{\psi_2}=\inf\left\{C>0: E[ \exp(|X/C|^2)]\leq 2 \right\}$$

Now $0\leq\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_F$ implies $\|A\|_2$ also has finite $\psi_2$ norm and is sub-Gaussian.

Comment: Since $A_{ij}$ are i.i.d. , maybe we ought not substitute all of them into $A_{k1}$ since they are independent r.v. :)

Comment: There are $n$ summands, each of which is bounded by $a^2$ or $b^2$, so if you want a bound, it's $nb^2$ or $na^2$. The *typical* value will be smaller, which is the whole point of the problem, but you were claiming a deterministic bound.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!